# How to populate items from one ObservableCollection but select a value from another ObservableCollection in a Picker in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

In .NET MAUI, the Picker is not selecting an item when the ItemsSource is a different object from the ItemsSource of the CollectionView.

How can I have populate a Picker with items from one ObservableCollection, but make the selected item a value from a single object in a different ObservableCollection?

I have the following `CollectionView` on a `ContentPage`. Within the Picker, the list of options is set by an `ObservableCollection<string>`. The list is working okay to populate those string selection options, but the picker is not focusing on the SelectedItem (string value from `models:Account`).

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding AccountList}" SelectedItem="{Binding AccountListSelectedItem}" WidthRequest="900">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Account">
            <Frame Padding="5" Margin="1" HeightRequest="60">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Entry Grid.Column="0" 
                           Text="{Binding Number}"  
                           x:DataType="models:Account" 
                           MaxLength="8" 
                           FontSize="11" 
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

                    <Entry Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="{Binding Name}"  
                           x:DataType="models:Account" 
                           ToolTipProperties.Text="{Binding Name}" 
                           FontSize="11" 
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" 
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                           Margin="3,0,0,0"/>

                    <Picker Grid.Column="2" 
                            FontSize="11" 
                            WidthRequest="250" 
                            HeightRequest="50" 
                            Margin="5,0,0,0"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" 
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                            SelectedItem="{Binding CategoryName}" 
                            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CategoryName}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:AccountKeyVM}}, Path=AvailableAccounts}"/>

                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

The ViewModel is:

```cs
public partial class AccountKeyVM : BaseViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<Account> accountList;

    [ObservableProperty]
    Account accountListSelectedItem;

    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<string> availableAccounts;
}
```

The Model for `Account` is:

```cs
public class Account
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

I have other Pickers which have hard-coded values as the ItemsSource as an array of type string. The selected index is an integer, so it picks up exactly as expected.

In this case, `Type` in `models:Account` is an integer. The view will correctly display the string correlating to the integer value.

```xml
<Picker Grid.Column="3" 
        FontSize="11" 
        WidthRequest="250"  
        x:DataType="models:Account" 
        HeightRequest="50" 
        Margin="10,0,0,0" 
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" 
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
        SelectedIndex="{Binding Type}">
        
    <Picker.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>...</x:String>
            <x:String>A</x:String>
            <x:String>B</x:String>
            <x:String>C</x:String>
            <x:String>D</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

Comment: I don’t think that is possible. As an alternative, consider adding a property to Account, containing the string to display. Then set `ItemDisplayBinding` to name of that property. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker#populate-a-picker-with-data-using-data-binding

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the problem, but, couldn't you update the AccountListSelectedItem setter to also update/populate availableAccounts?

Comment: To me `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CategoryName}"` is wrong and should be removed. `ItemDisplayBinding`: *Gets or sets a binding that selects the property that will be displayed for each object in the list of items.* and the item is of type `string` which has no such property

Comment: Sir Rufo’s suggestion is the beginning of another way to tackle it: Have Picker only work with strings. After removing ItemDisplayBinding, change SelectedItem to bind to a string property SelectedAccountName. In its setter, use name to look up corresponding Account, in a Dictionary. Store that in AccountListSelectedItem.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The question states that the `ItemsSource` points to `AvailableAccounts` which is pretty clear an `ObservableCollection<string>`, so each item is a `string` and that type does not have a property `CategoryName`. It is not another way it is plain wrong when you have `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CategoryName}"`

Comment: To me this is a bug in the Picker control. It depends at what time you load/bind the `Picker.ItemsSource` collection. Check out my [MCR Example @ github](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-76302378-Picker) where you have 4 cases (different load timings) and buttons to reload manually to play around with. The Picker inside the CollectionView is always showing nothing after loading - only after selection.

Comment: @SirRufo - yes, I agree with you. My point is that currently the attributes are an unworkable jumble. Two of them refer to CategoryName, which is a property on Account. ItemsSource is strings. Either everything changes to use string, or everything changes to use Account. My first comment was about changing source to Account. Your comment was a partial fix, given strings ItemsSource. I then described the rest of what I think is needed, for that to work.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The `Picker` control is buggy regarding `ItemsSource` binding (it also has different behavior on macOS and windows, have not tested on android/ios/tizen). So you have to go around that too

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I liked your second comment about binding to a property SelectedAccountName, but I think in this instance it may not work for my need being housed in a DataTemplate.

Comment: @SirRufo In reading through some documentation, I must have misinterpreted what ItemDisplayBinding was actually doing. Regardless, thank you for the link on github to the different cases. I'm going to play around with that a bit. For some context, the options in availableAccounts are dynamic based on a picker in a different section of the page. Just from first glance, I may need to take lead from one of your example and actually write an update function after that other picker changes to accomplish something like Case 5

Comment: If you get this working, please add Your Answer below. This may help others in the future.

Comment: Please override ToString in Account Class: public override string ToString(){return number +Name};